# How can I model a binary outcomes in time series using logistic regression?

Tags: r, time-series, logistic, spss, repeated-measures

My data has a binary outcome (attack or not attack), day (20 day in repeated measured design) and some covariates (nestling’s movement).
The objectives of my experiment are testing the effect of time and other factors and selecting useful variables affecting outcomes.

My data look like below

```
subject outcome Day nestling.move
   1        A    1      N 
   2        A    1      Y 
   3        A    1      Y 
   4        N    1      Y 
   5        N    1      Y 
   6        N    1      Y 
   7        N    1      Y 
   8        N    1      N 
   9        N    1      N 
   .        .    .      . 
   .        .    .      . 
   1        A    20     N 
   2        A    20     N
```

First of all, I simply transformed outcomes to ratios(attack rate for each day) and test if there is a correlation between attack rates and days by using Spearman’s rank correlation. But I think it is not a good way to test the effect of time on outcome.

I checked other [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81246/unable-to-fit-repeated-measures-in-r). and I think I should used an AR1 model with logistic regression since it could be a time-varying processes. However, I don't know how to do this with R or SPSS.

Is this the correct syntax to use in R?

```
model<- glmmPQL(outcome ~  nestling.move + Day, data=mydata, family=binomial,  random = ~ 1 | subject, correlation = corAR1(form=~Day|subject))
```

Comment: This looks right. You are on the right track with a random effects, logistic regression with autocorrelated errors.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

he following will perform a logistic regression:

```
m <- glm(outcome~ YOUR VARIABLES, data=yourData, family=binomial)
```

I'm not sure how you intend to integrate AR1 but you can test whether it even makes sense using the acf and pacf functions in R.

Comment: This does not address the PO's model situation, which definitely contains a random effect with correlated errors.

Comment: How did you determine it definitely contains correlated errors?

Comment: The PO says it does. It's longitudinal data, so the suspicion is reasonable. In any case, the PO's question seems to be how to include a random effect and AR(1) errors in a model. glm(), on its own, does not do that.

Comment: PO said it might. You may have noticed that I explicitly said that auto-correlation can be tested for and that I wasn't sure how AR1 would be included.

Answer (score -4):

for selecting usefull features that affect the outcome you could use some measure like PCA.
here is a discription [PCA toturial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.princeton.edu%2Fpicasso%2Fmats%2FPCA-Tutorial-Intuition_jp.pdf&ei=EMjEVJurH6bA7AbY8YDgAw&usg=AFQjCNG-Nfsu_KXDu8-UZTc2F-ZoD1AMUQ&sig2=XoIM7rAGwZ1T-uziAIPaOQ&bvm=bv.84349003,d.ZWU)

and here is a sample code :

(its in matlab but you could easily code it to other languages)

```
X = bsxfun(@minus, X, mean(X,1));           %# zero-center
C = (X'*X)./(size(X,1)-1);                  %'# cov(X)

[V D] = eig(C);
[D order] = sort(diag(D), 'descend');       %# sort cols high to low
V = V(:,order);
mydimension = 10;
newX = X * V(1:mydimension);
```

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with PCA